# Unlock iPhone X while screen is broken and won't turn on?

Tags: iphone, unlock

My iPhone X had a fault this evening (second time I've had an iPhone X die on me). The screen went bright white all of a sudden and then turned black, and it won't come back on.

The touchscreen itself appears to still be working, as I can click roughly where the lock buttons would be and can feel haptic feedback, but it's the display itself that is completely black.

I haven't backed up the iPhone in a while and need to back it up before I send it in for repairs, but I can't access it from iTunes while it is locked.

How can I unlock the screen without being able to see it? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this slightly unconventional approach. It would work easily if you can get your hands on an alternate working iPhone X, the same model as your iPhone X.

Place the other working iPhone X besides yours. Now based on the screen of working iPhone X, you can approximate the location of the on-screen controls.

First, attempt to turn off your iPhone X. Use the help of the working iPhone to locate the power-off slider. After you have turned off your iPhone, turn it back on. You'll be prompted to enter the device passcode. Use the working iPhone X to approximate the location of buttons and unlock your iPhone.

If this is the first time you are connecting your iPhone X to your Mac, you'll need to trust each other. Connect both your and the other iPhone X (which I am assuming was never connected to your Mac). You will get the approximate location of the Trust button on your iPhone.

Once you have successfully connected your iPhone, you can back it up in iTunes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use iTunes
   Launch the latest version of iTunes> Connect iPhone to the synced computer> iTunes successfully recognizes the iPhone> Click the device icon> Go to "Summary"> "Restore iPhone"> Confirm to reset the device to factory settings> Follow the prompts and select "From iTunes Backup Restore "to restore backup data.
2. Use Siri
   Press and hold the Home button to activate Siri> Let Siri "turn on VoiceOver"> Press the Home button to enter the unlock screen> Swipe left or right until the "Slide Unlock" option is selected> Double-tap twice to display the password page> Swipe left or right to Highlight the correct key on the keyboard> double-click to "enter" each key> slide to highlight Enter or done> double-click to submit the password.

In addition, the iCloud erase method can also [unlock iPhone X with broken screen](https://www.fonecope.com/iphone-screen-broken-cant-unlock.html).